# Fetching data from Codechef using PHP

Tags: php

This may seem a bit off-topic but I would be grateful if somebody helps out with this.
I have codechef ID's of few people. I want to monitor their performance like successfull submissions, total submissions etc. Unfortunately, Codechef doesn't provide an API for this. But some websites like Hackerearth do it anyway !

So I want to ask, what method (legal method) should I follow to fetch that data if I have usernames of those people ? 
And if I am doing this, is there anything illegal in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `Web Scrapping`. You can use `curl` or `file_get_contents()`.

Please have a look [here](http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scrape-tutorial/basic-php-scraping.php)